# Can't connect to the Tor Network

Tags: help, error, tor-install

So I've installed Tor onto my PC for the third time (Uninstalled previously because I didn't use it as much). The first two times it worked perfectly. I could connect, start up, etc but now it isn't working. I tried connecting directly and the connection got stuck at "Establishing an encrypted directory connection”. Upon getting this, I cancelled and started it up again. Now, it's stuck at "Connecting to the Tor network". I cancelled it one more time and started it up. It seemed like it was working and then gave me an error saying "Establishing an encrypted directory connection failed". I decided to search online and found out about the bridges. I tried using the normal Obfs4 Bridge and then the meek bridges and it still has not worked. Not sure what to do so I'm just posting this here and hoping someone can help me.

If it helps, here's the log:

```
06/01/2017 10:26:56.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/01/2017 10:26:57.000 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "C:\Users\The Dragon Cast\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc.orig.2" 
06/01/2017 10:27:18.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/01/2017 10:27:18.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/01/2017 10:27:18.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/01/2017 10:27:18.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/01/2017 10:27:18.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
06/01/2017 10:27:19.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
06/01/2017 10:31:30.400 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/01/2017 10:31:30.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/01/2017 10:31:30.400 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/01/2017 10:31:31.400 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
06/01/2017 10:31:39.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/01/2017 10:31:39.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/01/2017 10:31:39.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/01/2017 10:31:39.700 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/01/2017 10:31:42.000 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/01/2017 10:31:42.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/01/2017 10:31:42.000 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/01/2017 10:31:56.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/01/2017 10:31:56.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/01/2017 10:31:56.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/01/2017 10:31:56.500 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/01/2017 10:32:11.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host A832D176ECD5C7C6B58825AE22FC4C90FA249637 at 154.35.22.11:443) 
06/01/2017 10:32:11.600 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
06/01/2017 10:32:11.600 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 11; recommendation warn; host 7B126FAB960E5AC6A629C729434FF84FB5074EC2 at 192.99.11.54:443) 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [WARN] 12 connections have failed: 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [WARN]  11 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 12; recommendation warn; host BBB28DF0F201E706BE564EFE690FE9577DD8386D at 109.105.109.147:13764) 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [WARN] 14 connections have failed: 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [WARN]  12 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 13; recommendation warn; host 00DC6C4FA49A65BD1472993CF6730D54F11E0DBB at 154.35.22.12:4304) 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [WARN] 15 connections have failed: 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [WARN]  13 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 14; recommendation warn; host 752CF7825B3B9EA6A98C83AC41F7099D67007EA5 at 198.245.60.50:443) 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [WARN] 16 connections have failed: 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [WARN]  14 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 15; recommendation warn; host FC259A04A328A07FED1413E9FC6526530D9FD87A at 85.17.30.79:443) 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [WARN] 17 connections have failed: 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [WARN]  15 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 16; recommendation warn; host A09D536DD1752D542E1FBB3C9CE4449D51298239 at 83.212.101.3:50002) 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [WARN] 18 connections have failed: 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [WARN]  16 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
06/01/2017 10:32:15.000 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
06/01/2017 10:32:24.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/01/2017 10:32:24.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/01/2017 10:32:24.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/01/2017 10:32:24.000 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/01/2017 10:38:21.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 17; recommendation warn; host A2C13B7DFCAB1CBF3A884B6EB99A98067AB6EF44 at 0.0.2.0:3) 
06/01/2017 10:38:21.600 [WARN] 19 connections have failed: 
06/01/2017 10:38:21.600 [WARN]  17 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
06/01/2017 10:38:21.600 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
06/01/2017 10:39:55.200 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/01/2017 10:39:55.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/01/2017 10:39:55.200 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

Comment: Fixed now. Not sure what happened but after I restarted my pc, it seemed to be working fine.

Answer (score 4):

It's a big probability that it was a clock skew: on reboot many OS'es and distro's are updating the local time using NTP protocol, so - once you've got rebooted you had an accurate time and was able to join the network successfully.

Comment: After a Linux installation the time zone was correct but the time was bigger on the size of my timezone. Simple time correction fixed this Tor trouble. Later, I've selected the "Set time and date automatically" setting.

Comment: @it3xl at least in Russia here an ISP-driven attacks with a wrong time broadcasting are on the rise, so be careful with your system time

Comment: What other causes could the `[NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections` have, besides wrong time (my time is correct)?